# How do I only check for existing form fields values if it was modified?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to allow users the ability to update their profile, but can't seem to figure out how to only raise an error if the 2 fields `username, email` were modified, or if the user is not that user. As of now, I can't save the updates as the error is continuously popping up since the user has those values obviously. I've also tried `excludes` but couldn't get it to work right either. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class UpdateUserProfile(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(
    required=True,
    label='First Name',
    max_length=32,
)
last_name = forms.CharField(
    required=True,
    label='Last Name',
    max_length=32,
)
email = forms.EmailField(
    required=True,
    label='Email (You will login with this)',
    max_length=32,
)
username = forms.CharField(
    required = True,
    label = 'Display Name',
    max_length = 32,
)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')

    if (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()):
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.'
                                    'Please supply a different email address.')

    return email



def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']


    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user, user.username
```

views.py

```
def update_user_profile(request, username):
args = {}

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UpdateUserProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user-profile', kwargs={'username': form.save()[1]}))
else:
    form = UpdateUserProfile(instance=request.user)

args['form'] = form
return render(request, 'storytime/update_user_profile.html', args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if *another* user exists by excluding the current one:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class UpdateUserProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
    def clean_email(self):
        # ...
        if User.objects.filter(
            Q(username=username)|Q(email=email)
        ).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).exists():
            raise ...

        # for checking if both were modified
        if self.instance.email != email and self.instance.username != username:
            raise ...
```

One could further argue that this code belongs in the form's `clean` method as it validates field interdependencies.

Comment: Perfect, this indeed did it! Thanks!